# Creating a general purpose timer for execution of events and updating variables within a SpriteKit GameScene

Tags: swift, time, timer, sprite-kit

I'm building a game in SpriteKit and while I've seen various posts about making timers for executing run actions like `MoveTo`. But I wanted to know the best way to go about building a general purpose timer for the whole GameScene. Something that could be referenced almost globally, or passed by value to functions as to tell them when to execute. For example, as of now I spawn a boss on intervals of 50 killed enemies but I want to be able to reference this timer to spawn one, say every minute. I could have a variable at the top of GameScene that is updated in `Update`, but I'm not sure if this makes sense long term (especially with pausing or general reference). Any advice would be great.

Answer (score 3):

Timer implementation using `SKAction` may be of use for almost every aspect in a game:

- spawning enemies, updating time left labels, regenerating health, regenerating shields or whatever can be regenerated and so on...

There is an `update:` method with its passed `currentTime` parameter, where you can do whatever you can achieve using SKActions. It is up to you what you are going to use.

About using global timers. I don't really get what you are referring to and where you can have a need for them... Timers like described above, are often defined per scene, because usually, you don't have to count how much time is passed while transitioning between scenes. If you have to, then, we will think of something :) But, that is rare and I will skip that situation.

All of these timers, when game is paused, should be paused as well. You don't want to see that you have run out of time after a return from a phone call, right? Or you don't want to see full screen of enemies (which both would likely happen if you use `NSTimer` for time related actions). So as you can see, there is an NSTimer, but I would skip a story about it, because there are lot of posts, here on SO, where people debating about should we use it in SpriteKit or should we skip it. I would say,  just skip it because you don't need it at all. So using `SKAction` or `update:` method will allow you to have everything paused when game is interrupted (actions will be paused automatically).

On the other hand, implementing timers for a specific purpose, say implementing refilling lives feature, is not a task that `SKActions` (nor some update: method implementation) can solve. That is because you have to calculate how much time have passed since a certain moment, but a user can terminate an app in a meanwhile. In this case, using something like `NSUserDefaults` will give you a way to solve app termination, so you can continue counting from where you have left of next time user starts the app. But there is a catch... A user can mess with his clock, so you don't want to rely on client time, and this is usually solved using a server and its time. I guess this may be what you called "a global timer".

Comment: By global I mean a timer variable of sorts that can be referenced throughout the GameScene. So I could do something like: 'If(timer==60){ spawnBoss()}' or if timer%120==0){increment_enemy_speed()}' where timer is in seconds, I don't know if these even makes sense to do though?

Comment: And how would I pull that timing information out of the update function?

Comment: you would need to keep track of the delta times (change between current update and last update) and not track the time between pauses to do what you are thinking of doing,  or just use SKActions the correct way, with a `waitForDuration` followed by a `runBlock` that spawns boss